# Is there a way to re-hydrate the gapi.client access token between page loads?

Tags: google-oauth

The [use-token-model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model) documentation states that

> In the token based authorization model, there is no need to store
> per-user refresh tokens on your backend server.

It also states that

> In the Token model, an access token is not stored by the OS or
> browser, instead a new token is first obtained at page load time, or
> subsequently by triggering a call to requestAccessToken() through a
> user gesture such as a button press.

The trouble I am having is during development my page is continually reloading and I am having to re-connect each time.  I have workaround ideas, but I just wanted to confirm that there is no way to persist the token/session information in local storage to rehydrate gapi.client via gapi.client.setToken.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the access token in local storage. When the page reloads, you can then retrieve it and use `gapi.client.setToken()` to set the token for use.

Note that you will have to re-auth when the token expires, after 1 hour.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("u_token")
if (token) {
    gapi.client.setToken({access_token:token});
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I overlooked something but "I just wanted to confirm that there is no way to persist the token/session information in local storage to rehydrate gapi.client via gapi.client.setToken."  You suggest what I already tried.  That being said, I found that the following code will not prompt the user for credentials: tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });